# How to convert an array to a hash using Mongoid Pipeline?

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

Given a pipeline that emits an array of hashes.

Each `indicators` key has a value of an array:

```
[{
  "indicators" => [
     "SMA:1",
     "SMA:2",
     "SMA:3" ]},
  ...
```

How to use a pipeline to convert the `indicators` array to a hash to get:

```
[{
  "indicators" => {
     "SMA:1" => true,
     "SMA:2" => true,
     "SMA:3" => true }},
 ...
```

Comment: @potashin - No, that is a Ruby question. I am interested in using the Mongoid Pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $map to map your array from `['v1', 'v2', 'v3']` to `[['v1', true], ['v2', true], ['v3', true]]`, then use https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/ to convert that to a hash.